# Emotion API's For tracking human interesets

Tags: java, android, json, web-services

I am trying to implement a application to recognized human facial expressions(happiness,sadness,boring, etc,) then after automatically selecting a song which suitable for current emotion of the person, if he is sad system playing enjoyable song, how can i do this thing, if any API's already have? any examples for me?

Comment: Requests for libraries are off topic here.  If you're asking how to do it from scratch-  that's enough material for several phds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding，your core need is facial expression recognition.there is an API ready for you ,emotion API by Microsoft https://azure.microsoft.com/zh-cn/services/cognitive-services/emotion/.Which Can detect emotions including anger, contempt, disgust, fear, happiness, neutral, sadness and surprise. You can think of these emotions across cultural boundaries, usually by certain facial expressions.

example:you can refer to How-old, a popular APP which Can measure the characters of age and Gender through photos.the different is:it's a light application Supported by another Microsoft API(Project Oxford),But I think you can get some inspiration from it.